# What methods exist for obtaining the class feature wildshape without ever being a druid?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, wild-shape

Any methods are acceptable: powers, classes, items, spells, alternate class features, racial sub-levels, templates; the more comprehensive, the better. Any official or designated official 3.x source is acceptable.

The character in question must obtain the wildshape class feature specifically, no other form of shape alteration will qualify. Due to the same plot, story, and thematic restrictions, the character may not take any levels in druid.

For purposes of identifying wildshape, if it would allow one to take a class or feat or use an item which has a prerequisite of wildshape, then it qualifies.

Thank you.

Comment: There's an awful lot of these - are you sure you want to allow both 3e and 3.5e?

Comment: This might be closed as “too broad”. What is your actual situation that you're hoping something in this list will solve? How about we cut out the middle and just solve your actual problem?

Comment: Also, what level of similarity to wild shape is necessary: does it have to use that name, does it have to specify some level of compatibility with the druid’s wild shape, does it have to stack with druid levels if you had them? Or do you just want anything that can turn you into an animal?

Comment: We play 3.x: all official 3.0 which hasn't been updated to 3.5 is allowed, plus all official 3.5. For various theme, plot, and story reasons, the character cannot be a druid, but also, must learn wildshape. Edited question to specify the wildshape class feature.

Comment: So I'm clear, can you confirm that the character doesn't need wild shape *for* anything, and, instead, that you just need to have the actual words *wild shape* written down on the character sheet somewhere. Also, out of curiosity, can druids in the campaign actually *tell the difference* between a creature capable of true wild shape and a creature that can just use the supernatural ability alternate form?

Comment: The term "class feature wildshape" has a very specific meaning in third edition terminology. Just writing the words wild shape has no meaning mechanically. Therefore, I need exactly what I said: the class feature named wildshape. And of course the character will use it to change shape as specified.

Comment: Clarified the question again to be specific to a single character, rather than general, though the scope of the question remains unchanged.

Comment: I imagine that a psionic/magical means of detecting the difference could be developed through research,  though I am unaware of anything official. Through concatenation of various rules the existence of such an ability can be implied, but I do not believe it is stated.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, and I didn't mean to be glib or dismissive. I meant the *precise* kind of wild shape doesn't matter for the character. For example, the feat Oaken Resilience (*CD* 82) has a prerequisite that the creature be able to use wild shape to assume the form of a plant—such a specific kind of wild shape is unnecessary for this character? Likewise, the template Mulhorandi divine minion grants the supernatural ability fast wild shape—is an ability with a slightly different name *close enough* for this character?

Comment: No problems, my apologies if I came back across  short or snippy. The key identifier for wildshape is if it can be used to qualify for things requiring wildshape. Generally speaking anything using phraseology "same as", or "functions as" gets a pass in most circles.

Comment: Likewise no problem. Just so everything's clear, no one's trying to give you a hard time by demanding greater specificity. It's just that it's unusual to *want* a thing yet not *need* that thing *for* anything *else*. Often — like, seriously, *almost always* — questions like this one signal an underlying [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). That yours *isn't* (*I just want wild shape, okay?*) caught the community—well, *me*, anyway—off guard. [I apologize for not taking the question at face value.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5498/8610)

Comment: You are most gracious. I can do naught but humble accept, and hope in turn to be accepted. In this particular case, wildshape was the lock, and sources thereof are the key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Classes, templates, and feats

Surreal's [Lists of Stuff](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1412.0) mentions—and A_soo's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84387/8610) describes—many of the classes granting wild shape and its alternatives. (Omitting, for example, the variant totem druid (*Dragon* #335 87) is totally acceptable: the level 1 supernatural ability [totem shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/39540/8610) "uses all the same rules as wild shape" but isn't actually *called* wild shape. *Sigh*. Good thing that doesn't matter as druid levels are off the table anyway.) KRyan's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84386/8610) describes the feat Initiate of Horus-Re (*CV* 31) with its limited wild shape and the template [Mulhorandi divine minion](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20050209a) with its variant fast wild shape.

In addition, the prestige class shapeshifter (originally *Oriental Adventures* 45-6 and updated to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* by the *Dragon* #318 article "Oriental Adventures Update: Eastern Flavor" (35-6)) grants explicitly and progressively better wild shape starting at level 1. In addition to the requirements base attack bonus +3 and Concentration 10 ranks, a creature needs to meet the special requirement Alternate Form: "Must either know *polymorph self* or have a natural alternate form, *alter self*, *polymorph self*, or shapechange ability" (*OA* 46). Despite *polymorph self* not being a spell in *3.5*, the update left that untouched; talk to the DM and see if "minor adjustments" (*DMG* 4) can be made to these requirements (like expanding them!) to bring them in line with the *3.5* revision.

## Race

The planetouched race worghest (*Dragon* #350 56-7) has the supernatural ability change shape allowing it at will to take a standard action to assume the form of a wolf but also allowing it to "take feats requiring the druid's wild shape ability as a prerequisite." This makes available options that *should* only be accessible to creatures with *actual* wild shape—like Aberration Wild Shape (*Lords of Madness* 178) or Bestial Charge (*Complete Champion* 56)—which might make druids perceive a worghest's already supernatural ability change shape *as* wild shape. Maybe this is close enough?

While a worghest normally mandates a Level Adjustment of +2, a generous reading of *Player's Guide to Faerûn* on Variants: Races with Level Adjustments (190-1) lets a planetouched creature change its type from outsider to humanoid (planetouched) to suffer no Level Adjustment, but it's likely only by accident that these rules apply to the worghest, so ask the DM and good luck. Also, [like many creatures that can assume other forms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74192/8610), changing *from* wolf *to* worghest may be an issue.

## Magic items

The *Dragon* #324 Magic Shop column "Power at a Price" includes the following:

> #### *The Skin of Kaletor*
>
> This bearskin cloak… gives off a powerful rotting stench that is immediately noticeable and incurs a −6 penalty on all Charisma-based skill checks and wild empathy checks. When wearing a *skin of Kaletor*, a druid can use the wild shape ability as if he were four levels higher than his current druid level. Additionally, any non-druid who wears the cloak can use the wild shape ability once per day as a 4th-level druid.
>
> *Faint transmutation; CL 4th; Craft Wondrous Item, creator must be a druid; Price 12,000 gp; Weight 10 lb.*

Obviously, this item has problems—it's a little heavy, don't you think?—, but chief among them is that a level 4 druid doesn't *have* the supernatural ability wild shape; given the *skin*'s drawback, a DM should forgive this oversight and house rule the skin to level 5. If the DM doesn't, the *amulet of wild shape* (*Magic of Faerûn* 167) (40,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants wild shape as a level 5 druid… or increases existing wild shape ability by 4 effective druid levels to a maximum of 20. The *amulet*'s advantage is that it's not limited to once per day like the *skin*, but the *skin*'s not limited to an effective druid level of 20. O, the *skin* has the advantage of lower price, too, if that's a concern. (Ask the DM what happens if a creature gains a level while wearing a borrowed *skin*, takes the feat Extra Wild Shape (*Complete Divine* 81) (or willfully misreads Fast Wild Shape (*CD* 81-2)), then returns the *skin* to its owner. I suspect the creature's head explodes and it dies but results may vary.)

(Combining *amulet* then *skin* with the [*druid's vestment*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#vestment-druids) (*DMG* 268) ([10,000 gp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62834/8610); 0 lbs.) and the magic item set *trappings of the beast* (*Complete Champion* 135-6 *et al.* collectively costing over 50,000 gp) lets the wearer use wild shape like a level 10 druid except that it's 6 times per day and that it's usable as a swift action, which is pretty cool, and it had better be cool: the whole shebang costs over 100,000 gp!)

Comment: Excellent catches! I was not aware of these items at all.

Comment: A level 5 Druid can only use Wild Shape once a day, so the once a day restriction on the cloak isn't any different than the Amulet of Wild Shape, they both grant a non-druid one use of Wild Shape a day, it's just explicit rather than implicit.

Answer (score 6):

**Classes that definitely give Wild Shape as a class feature**

- Druid 5 (Player's Handbook)
- Ranger 5 (Unearthed Arcana variant)
- Abolisher 1 (PrC, Lords of Madness)
- Lion of Talisid 3 (PrC, Book of Exalted Deeds)
- Moonspeaker 5 (PrC, Races of Eberron)

**Other stuff that might count**

- Landforged Walker 5 (PrC, Secrets of Xen'Drik):  Feature is called "Plant Shape," but description says it "is otherwise like the wild shape druid class feature (PH 37)" (i.e., aside from being restricted to plants).  Might count, depending on your use case and DM.
- Swanmay 1 (PrC, Book of Exalted Deeds):  Feature is called "Shifting," but description says it "is identical to the druid's wild shape ability, except that the swanmay can only assume the form of a swan."
- Primeval 1 (PrC, Frostburn):  Feature is called "Primeval Form," but description says that it "functions similarly to the druid's wild shape ability, except the alternate form chosen must be selected when the character takes his first level of primeval and cannot be changed after that."
- Blighter 3 (PrC, Complete Divine):  Feature is called "Undead Wild Shape," but description says it's "a version of the wild shape ability."
- Mulhorandi Divine Minion (template, [online](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112041907/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20050209a)):  Definitely gives Wild Shape, but it's a template, not a class, so it's not technically as a class feature.  Also this is Grade A Known Cheese.

---

Most info in this post is from the [lists of stuff](http://www.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1412.0).  Know them, use them, love them.

Comment: I do believe there are a couple of wildshape sources in Oriental Adventures, which were updated to 3.5 in a certain Dragon Magazine. Shapechanger and Bear Warrior, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @user30200 *CW* updates the *OA* bear warrior; neither gets wild shape, the latter likening the transformation instead to *polymorph*.

Comment: Guess I mis-remembered, in the latter case, hopefully not in the case of the former?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Lists of Stuff](http://www.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1412.0), wild shape is available from

- <s>Druid 5</s>
- Variant ranger 5, *Unearthed Arcana*
- Wild monk 6, *Dragon* vol. 324
- Abolisher prestige class 1 (ECL 7), *Lords of Madness*
- Lion of Talisid prestige class 2 (ECL 8), *Book of Exalted Deeds*
- **Hawk Only**—Initiate of Horus-Re feat  (requires cleric, paladin, or ranger 4), *Champions of Valor*

And, of course, there is the psychotic [Mulhorandi Divine Minion](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20050209a) LA +1 or +2 template, which grants *fast* wild shape and is restricted to one of a few forms based on patron deity.